# How can I find data to test Facial Tracking

Tags: computer-vision

I thought of downloading random profile pictures of people on facebook but that might not be entirely legal.

Are there some good ways in which I can get a big sample of pictures of people faces without risking violating anyone's privacy?

What do Computer Vision scientists use for their test cases/studies?

I am not planning on releasing this study anywhere it is just for sake of comparison between different kind of algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [The Color FERET Database](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/colorferet.cfm)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else is wondering where they can find a huge database for faces from different angles take a look at

http://www.milbo.org/muct/index.html

and

http://web.mit.edu/emeyers/www/face_databases.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this page:

http://face-rec.org/databases/

It summarizes various face recognition databases.